# changing the text in button when it is clicked on running a daemon thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, embedded-ruby

I am new to rails.I have a button and on clicking that button a daemon thread is initiated and i want the text in that button to change into "Executing"  the code in view is

```
<td>
<% if data.vName == 'BuzzCity' or data.vName == 'neXva'%>
  <%= button_to "Start", { :action=> :execute_rake },  :remote => true  %>
<%end%>
</td>
```

and in the controller is

```
def execute_rake
  vendor_name = 'neXva'#params[:vendorName]
  @async = ::AppMall::AsyncTask.new()
  if vendor_name == 'BuzzCity'

  elsif  vendor_name == 'neXva'

  else
   render :text => 'Unknown vendor'  
   return    
  end
 render :text => 'Executing'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this option `:disable_with`

Try this,

```
<%= button_to "Start", { :action=> :execute_rake },  :remote => true, :disable_with => 'Executing...'  %>
```

Comment: Check the 5th example in this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

Comment: i did this but the also it is going to the controller and its executing the else loop and a text is rendered in another page. Is it possible to set the text in a button from the controller

Comment: @Sajeer try this 1) remove the render text code and store that text in a `@text` variable 2) set id to the `button_to` like `<%= button_to "Start", {:action => :execute_rake}, :remote => true, :id => "button_id", :method => :get %>` 3) and finally in your execute_rake.js.erb file add this `$("#button_id").val("<%= @text %>")`   Note: don't forget to use gem 'jquery-rails'